# Spring Web Sockets Chat Application

Tags: sockets, web, broken-pipe

[Server Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfHna.png)[Spring Web Socket Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luNhH.png)

I developed Chat application and deployed in linux server and I have Deskrom Desk Support application to send chat messages, Chat Server is started with out any error. I am using Web Sockets Stomp protocol.

After I sent message from Desk application the messages are saving in Chat application but in the middle I am getting the above attached Broken Pipe exception.

Please help me to fix the problem.

Comment: Please provide suggestions to fix the problem.

Comment: You need to provide the code to know where the pipe is broken and it will help to understand the problem.